# Radio Button in Asp.net Webform for multiple choice question

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating multiple-choice questions in ASP.NET Web Forms. I am getting the question and multiple choice options from the database. Is there a simple way to hide the 3rd option (C) when there are only two inputs (`True` or `False`)? Thank you in advance!

Here is aspx code:

```
<tr>
  <td class="style7">A.</td>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RbA" runat="server" GroupName="gtog"/>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="style7">B.</td>
  <td style="text-align: left">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RbB" runat="server" GroupName="gtog" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="style7">C.</td>
  <td style="text-align: left" >
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RbC" runat="server" GroupName="gtog" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does your code look like for generating this markup? The answer is going to rely more on how you’re processing the data from the database, and less on what the markup that it’s outputting looks like.

Comment: "I  am getting the question and multiple choice options from the database" - please show how you are doing this, then we don't have to guess at your database structure.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I forgot to include the backend code, but Jon helped me with an example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we have no info as to what is happening on your backend I'll keep this generic.

Add an id and `runat="server` to the final table row. You can then access that serverside to hide an show the row.

**ASPX**

```
<tr id="rowC" runat="server">
  <td class="style7">C.</td>
  <td style="text-align: left" >
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RbC" runat="server" GroupName="gtog" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

**C#**

```
if(answerCount == 2)
{
   rowC.visible = false;
}
```

On a side note, you *really* should avoid using tables for layout. It is now 2020 there are many better ways to layout a form (or anything).

Comment: Thanks Jon! It helped. Sorry that I forgot to include my backend code but you guessed it right! Thanks once again. I am pretty new to web development. Can you suggest some ways to layout a form? or some links? Thank you

Comment: @Peter: Out of curiosity, if you’re new to web development, why are you learning Web Forms? I take it you’re working on a project that still uses them? I ask because there is a lot of extra wiring and some prickly corners that you’ll run into with Web Forms which are pretty elegantly side-stepped with Microsoft’s newer MVC or Pages frameworks. But, of course, we all understand needing to work with legacy code! Regardless, enjoy the learning.

Comment: @Peter: There are a handful of alternatives to tables for layout. The simplest is just to use `div`s—or some other container—to group blocks of content and then use e.g. `float: left` so multiple cells can align on a single row. That has the advantage of allowing cells to wrap onto multiple rows for smaller screens, thus providing some _responsiveness_. That said, there are also newer approaches such as CSS’s *FlexBox* which I’d recommend looking into. They require a bit more learning, but also provide a lot more flexibility and avoid some gotchas when moving beyond basic scenarios.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyCaney for useful information. I will surely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check if the item from the database is of Type bool - if this is true make 3rd Options(C) hidden.

So create a variable that checks the item from the database, if its a Boolean then add hide RbC.

```
Type b = itemFromDB.GetType(); 
if(b is bool)
  RbC.hidden = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Aman. It makes more sense now. Can you give me an example of "Type b = itemFromDB.GetType();" or little more explanation.

Comment: I'm assigning the result from itemFromDB.GetType() to b. So  to find out if there are only two inputs, I want to know if the input is a true or false i.e a bool type. So all you need to find out is if there are two inputs, the way I'm doing it is to check if it's a bool. You can do it however you want, maybe even if RbA is not null or not empty. Then toggle RbC based on that.

Comment: GetType() checks the type of the item from db. I'm assuming the item is stored as a boolean in the database

Comment: Thank you @Aman. I got the idea, I should have provided the backend code as well. And Thank you once again!